# Which SQL Query takes more time? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

How to check which sql query is taking more time? (MYSQL)
Im using a dedicated Linux server and the website is consuming 1 GB of RAM, the company says its because of SQL queries (MYSQL).
Can anybody tell me how to check which sql queries is taking more time and utilizing more resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Mysql Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: You have to enable it first in your my.ini configuration file, and then, it will be with the mysql logs files.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you tell me where is that my.ini file?

Comment: It depends, are you on Linux or Windows ? Debian ? Fedora ? Red Hat ? Suse ?

Comment: I'm at Linux server with CentOS.

Comment: Well, it should be located at /etc/my.cnf

Comment: And I just realized that it's not my.ini but my.cnf ... my bad... sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Mysql provides the EXPLAIN keyword to display the execution plan of queries; simply put "EXPLAIN" in front of your query, and Mysql will display the execution plan of that query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: That is what i want to know which query is taking time. How would I know for which query i need to put "explain". they are thousands of queries running on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to see which of your queries can be improved. The [MySQL logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-logs.html) might also give you a hint about what's using up so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL memory usage, while it does have to do with queries being run also has to do with the configuration of MySQL itself, and the amount of data being stored in MySQL.  You can limit the amount or memory used by MySQL by tweaking the settings in my.cnf  However, giving less memory to MySQL is a sure way to slow it down. This can be offset someuhat by using proper indexes for the queries you are running.  For a good overview of memory options, see [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/17/mysql-server-memory-usage/)

Comment: Thanks but it is very detailed.

Comment: I realize it's a little bit of a long read.  However, understanding MySQL memory usage is a little bit of a complicated subject.  While changing queries can reduce the amount of memory you use, or allow you to use the memory you have more wisely, it doesn't set hard limits on how much memory will be used.  If you have a database with 1 GB of data in it (indexes and data), and you allow your database to use 1 GB of memory (through settings in my.cnf), your memory usage will almost always reach 1 GB after a long enough time period unless that data isn't being accessed at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right my database size is 1 GB and almost 700 MB are consumed by tracking information of each user. I think i should delete that so that i can increase the performance.